# Make datalabels formatter for pie without slice

Tags: javascript, highcharts

I try to build a pie graphic with **Highcharts**, but I've a problem with the option **dataLabels** and the **formatter**.

I've a **json** :

```
[
{"name":"libelle","data":["TROUILLE","BEARN"]},
{"name":"Nombre","data":[12,24]}
]
```

I would like to have the label :

```
BEARN : 66,66 %
```

So, I tried to write this :

```
dataLabels: {enabled: true,
formatter: function() {return '<b>'+ this.y +'</b>: '+ Highcharts.numberFormat(this.percentage, 2) +' %';}}
```

My result :

```
Slice : 66,66 %
```

I don't have problem with the percentage but I've a problem to access to the series **libelle**.

How can I do that ?

Thank you for your help.

*Geo-x*

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to merge your data from JSON, or change JSON. So two possible solutions:

1) Change JSON to format:

```
[{
  "y":12,
  "name":"TROUILLE"
}, { 
  "y":24,
  "name":"BEARN"
}]
```

2) Merge data in JS: http://jsfiddle.net/zwb5toe9/1/

```
var data = [],
    json = [{
    "name": "libelle",
        "data": ["TROUILLE", "BEARN"]
}, {
    "name": "Nombre",
        "data": [12, 24]
}];

$.each(json[1].data, function(i, e) { //loop over "Nombre"
    data.push({
        y: e,
        name: json[0].data[i]
    });
});

$('#container').highcharts({
    plotOptions: {
        pie: {
            dataLabels: {
                enabled: true,
                formatter: function () {
                    return '<b>' + this.key + '</b>: ' + Highcharts.numberFormat(this.percentage, 2) + ' %';
                }
            }
        }
    },
    series: [{
        type: 'pie',
        name: 'Browser share',
        data: data
    }]
});
```

Comment: Thank you for your help Pawel. The problem is, it's the third time what I change my json format because I always had a problem with this, with the label or with the graphic. So last time I used this json format with this tutorial : [link](http://blueflame-software.com/blog/how-to-create-dynamic-x-axis-data-using-json/ ). So you confirm it's impossible for me with this json format to take the value of my **libelle** ?

Comment: Okay, but you are referring to the tutorial for xAxis (kind of linear axis). Meanwhile you are using pie chart, which is without xAxis ;) Also, as I said above, you don't have to change format, simply use second solution.

Comment: Yes I think it's a good idea ! I understand what you say but I hoped to have only one json format for all the graphic :-) . Thank you very much and have a nice day !